# PHP PDO: Returning Results From The DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP PDO to make a simple movie storage that shows name of movies and some information about them based on MySQL table.

Here is my code:

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM films');
if($query->rowCount()){
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo '<td>', $r->id, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->name, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->year, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->actor, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->director, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->imdb, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->watched, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->starred, '</td>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<td>No Results!</td>';    
}
```

Now when I have more than one record, it does not go to next row of table and it just adds it to the 1st row:

[image]

So what is going wrong here? How can I correctly go to the next row of table in order to show table records properly?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot to echo the table rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, a separate `<tr>` is required for each iteration.

Please correct the code to:

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM films');
if($query->rowCount()){
    while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>', $r->id, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->name, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->year, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->actor, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->director, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->imdb, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->watched, '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $r->starred, '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No Results!</td></tr>';
}
```

This will ensure that each record will have its on `<tr>` where all data will be shown in `<td>`s.

Comment: Thank u, but when I added `<tr>` & `</tr>` inside the `while` loop, it worked fine!